# Serialize a POJO to JSON with GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I pull in some JSON, deserialize it to a POJO, edit some properties of the object, and now I want to serialize it back to JSON with GSON and send it back.

How do i serialize a javabean to JSON with GSON?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
Pojo myPojo = new Pojo();

Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(myPojo);
```

Comment: I knew it was that easy. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. There is very nice documentation from Google provided on project wiki: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Comment: [How to add Gson dependency to your android app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51149777/2396539)

Answer (score 8):

The gson.toJson() returns a String, not a JsonObject.

If you want to get a real JsonObject better do this:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JsonObject json = (JsonObject)parser.parse(new Gson().toJson(myPojo));
```

Comment: What is the 'parser' here?

Comment: JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(); JsonObject json = (JsonObject)parser.parse(new Gson().toJson(myPojo));