# Is there an easier way to add gson to my project?

Tags: android

How do I add gson to my project with gradle? I only see people adding files to their projects. I don't want to download the project and put it in mine.

Comment: In general we encourage posters to show what they have tried, or what research they have done. I am too late to note this on the question, however - it seems you have a quick answer already!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In app/build.gradle:

```
 dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
}
```

Comment: Poetry! So simple, yet too correct. Muchas gracias senior.

Comment: The latest version is 2.8.0 as of Mar 2017

Comment: 2.8.2 as of 20-Sep-2017.

Comment: now `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'` as _compile_ has been deprecated

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Android Studio you can use the following workflow instead of manually changing Gradle files:

1. File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> app -> Dependencies Tab
2. Click '+' in the bottom left corner and select "Library dependency"
3. In the search field type: "gson" and click Search
4. Select "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5"

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the screen shot , made life much easier !

Answer (score 4):

Add following to project’s `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
}
```

[Here](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/getting-started-with-google-gson.html) is the link for more info.

Answer (score 0):

`compile` is obsolete use `implementation` instead

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

}
```

P.S. version of 08/07/2019

Answer (score 0):

This the new version (2022)

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.10'
}
```