# How convert POJO to BSON with Google GSON?

Tags: gson

To convert a POJO to BSON with Jackson I know bson4jackson (http://www.michel-kraemer.com/binary-json-with-bson4jackson). Is there an equivalent with Google GSON?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725317/serialize-a-pojo-to-json-with-gson)

I have used gson as such:

- convert to pojo:

  `Gson gsonObj= new Gson();`

  `MyPojo mypojoObj = gsonObj.fromJson( someJsonString, MyPojo.class);`
- then convert to json string:

  `String s=gsonObj.toJson(mypojoObj);`

Also there should be a 1-1 correspondence of all parameters' names in MyPojo and the json string. You can test it out. I believeOnly those that match are serialized.

for example if:

```
class MyPojo
{
    public String xString;
    public String yString;
    ...
}
```

then with:

```
MyPojor= gsonObj.fromJson("{\"xString\":\"1\",\"yString\":\"1\",\"zString\":\"1\"}", MyPojor.class);

return gsonObj.toJson(r);
```

you get:

```
{"xString":"1","yString":"1"}
```

you can test the case where a parameter is not requested for serialization.