# android retrofit ,post whole Pojo using this format

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to post this kind of request in retrofit2 so if someone have idea about it then it would be great help of mine.

```
reqObject={"task":"singleUser","taskData":{"userID":"1"}}
```

Comment: use Gson and convert your pojo to json using it. Here is one example http://stackoverflow.com/a/8725397/842607

Comment: did you try it in  postman?

Comment: @Manoj yes I did tried in postman

Comment: @JimitPatel here "reqObject" will appear as key for whole json object using Gson here will not make any sense,please have a look at the url i want it like this ->   singleUserData.php?reqObject= {   "task": "singleUser",   "taskData": {     "userID": "1"} }

Comment: your taskData will be another Pojo which will be used by your root Pojo.

Comment: @PratikVyas hold up, you want to pass the json in a query parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, good Question It is some what **not understandable** for **`Beginner`**.

So I combining  some Answers for you.

### first step

make your Json -> model class (or POJO class)

> 1. [From GsonFormattor plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7654-gsonformat)

This plug-in convert your Json to Model class

[image]

> 2. [Pojo genrator](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Go to this link , copy and paste Your Json and simply make your model class.

OK , we completed our first step

## Second Step

Set all value to your Model class what You want from `getter() setter()`.

Retrofit having `@Body`  annotation  that use in your case

```
@POST("/jayson")
FooResponse postJson(@Body MyGsonModelClass body);
```

Where `MyGsonModelClass` is class we made from ***first step***.

Comment: If you still you having  problem to understand i can add more detail for that.

Comment: thanks for replying @vishal I know how to convert json to pojo http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ ,but it make complex situation here as reqObject={"task":"singleUser","taskData":{"userID":"1"}} is not simple but key value pojo where making this pojo creating complex situation as in output iwant this: singleUserData.php?reqObject= {   "task": "singleUser",   "taskData": {     "userID": "1"} }

Comment: what is the setuation?

Comment: well i want my request url like this
 singleUserData.php?reqObject= {   "task": "singleUser",   "taskData": {     "userID": "1"} }
so how can we do this in retrofit

Comment: see its depends on url   what is url type ?
its row data or url encoded ?

Comment: it is row data url

Comment: i think u have to try @query with ("reqObject")   and its value is simple jsonobject