# how to do a PUT using retrofit with a JSONObject that contains a JSONArray

Tags: android, json, mobile, retrofit2

I'm trying to shift over from volley to retrofit and I don't fully understand how to do a PUT with a JSONObject that contains a JSONArray.

The JSONObject body that I want to send to the server should look like this:

```
{
“account”: [
    {“availability”: “offline”} 
]}
```

here is my pojo

```
public class AvailabilityModel {

JSONObject account;

public AvailabilityModel(JSONObject account) {
    this.account = account;
 }
}
```

and my interface

```
public interface AvailabilityAPI {

@Headers( "Content-Type: application/json" )
@PUT(PATH)
Call<AccountParentModel> setAvailability(@Path("parameter") String accountId, @Body AvailabilityModel object);

class Factory {

    private static AvailabilityAPI service;

    public static AvailabilityAPI getInstance() {

        if (service == null) {

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(App.BASE_URL)
                    .build();

            return service = retrofit.create(AvailabilityAPI.class);
        } else {
            return service;
        }
    }
}

}
```

and finally, In my activity I do this:

```
 JSONObject account = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    try {
        obj.put("availability", "offline");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    array.put(obj);
    try {
        cloudNumber.put("account", array);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "JSONObj sent to the server is: " + account);

    AvailabilityModel availabilityModel = new AvailabilityModel(account);

        AvailabilityAPI.Factory.getInstance().setAvailability(accountId, availabilityModel).enqueue(new Callback<AccountParentModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CloudNumberParentModel> call, Response<CloudNumberParentModel> response) {
            Log.e("HomeActivity", "Success: availability = " + response.body().cloudNumbers.get(0).getAvailability());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CloudNumberParentModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), " No good bro " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

the problem with this is the server receives it in this format:

```
{“nameValuePairs”:{“account”:{“values”:[{“nameValuePairs”:{“availability”:“available”}}]}}}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: obviously you should build proper model class instead using `JSONObject account;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont do like that..

let me give some brief to simply understand you about that.

**step 1.   take your json reqest .**
In your case

```
{  “account”: [   {“availability”: “offline”}    ]}
```

**Step 2 . make model class.**
That i describe at here [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42951638/3513479)

So in your case  your model class is.

```
public class AvailabilityModel {


private List<AccountBean> account;

public List<AccountBean> getAccount() {
    return account;
}

public void setAccount(List<AccountBean> account) {
    this.account = account;
}

public static class AccountBean {
    /**
     * availability : offline
     */

    private String availability;

    public String getAvailability() {
        return availability;
    }

    public void setAvailability(String availability) {
        this.availability = availability;
    }
}
}
```

**Step 3 : putting value inside model class**

first

```
AccountBean account =  new AccountBean();  
account.setAvailability("offline");
```

now take one array

```
List<AccountBean>list = new List<AccountBean>();
list.add(account);
```

so above is your list  of account. now one step to complete make model.

```
AvailabilityModel model =new AvailabilityModel();  
model. setAccount(list);
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you very much Patel :)