# What are the checks to take into consideration for one time api call of static data in android?

Tags: android, api

I have many APIs in my application, which gives static data, and been used at several places.So instead of making that call at all places i want to call it once and store it locally. So i have three question

1) what conditions to take care for that for this. 
2) where to call the API ? At the time of launching of app, if yes then there are many API which need to be called.
3)Is this a good practice to do so? And what to do if API call gets failed.

Comment: its all up to your api responce use in your app.

Comment: @Vishal Patel Can you elaborate more. I mean in my app one of the api is calling getDestination for showing all the destination to be displayed. this is been used at 7 places. This might help you to help me. :)

Comment: Are you using synchronous API calls or asynchronous?

Comment: @Mohammaed Atif asynchronous API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making synchronous API calls, then one good approach is

```
public class APIHandler{
    public static class API1{
        private static int data1 = -1;
        public static int getData1(Context context){
            if(data1 < 0){
                return getResponse();
            }else{
                return data1;
            }
        }

        private static int getResponse(){
            int response;
            //write your synchronous API call method here
            response = 1; //your actual response
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

This is basically singleton implementation, if your variable has some values then it will return that variable otherwise it will fetch the value by making API call and store it. Here `API1` class is for one of your APIs and for each API you can make another class. And variable `data1` is initialized to -1 considering all your values will be greater than 0.

> This is not a good implementation as it will block your main thread.

**Approach-2 (recommended)**
Case-1:
If your API sends same value everytime, then you can make the API call once in your Application class and store those values in SharedPreference or Realm/SQLite and no need to make calls from next time onwards.

case-2:
If your API sends different value, then make the API call from application class everytime and store those values in constants.

If number of API calls are too high, then you can also make these calls from `IntentService` and start these services in your Application class. this will make sure that response is fetched and will not affect your main thread too. Only thing you must be careful is with the ordering of the calls. Call the important APIs before not so important ones.

Comment: I have at-least 5 APIs to call, so i am making async call. otherwise it will stuck on and will not look responsive to user. And server is sending same value for now but in future it might change.. Thanks for immediate response.

Comment: No issues, you can create intent services to handle each API and start those service in your Application class. this will update your values without affecting your main thread. But make sure to store those retrieved values. If necessary you can even attach broadcasts to notify the class that call has been successful

Comment: Ohh okay, This is a good idea. I have never used this approach before but will try that for sure.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

let me share brief some scenario with you.

->  whenever your API response needed with many pages so you have to store someplace.
  you have several options.

before that I suggest you For best practice to convert your [response to Model class.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42951638/3513479)

- Static Response:  If Your response dependent means without 1st-time call API not to go further. In short no background call for API. Then make Your model class  static.

> public static MyModelClass ;
>    myModelClass = assignYourResponce ; //
>   we will gives all value to model class

Now you can use response throughout the app.
But mark it without first response success you can't go further.

- SharedPref :  Using model class you  also store you response to preference and get with model class. Using GSON library provided by google.

Happy coding :)

Comment: I am already using retrofit, and my data might change in the future, so will store that in arraylist every-time app launches, will give a check whenever want to display, that data is empty or not. Will work right?? Thansk for response.

Comment: no dont check data empty because when server change data u havent any affect at your local side.

Comment: check every time when app open in your case